# R: rolling/moving average split by month

Tags: r, ggplot2, dataframe, plyr, dplyr

I am trying to calculate a rolling/moving average by month. For example, using the economics data from the ggplot2 package, I want to construct an accompanying time series that represents the 3-year rolling average of each month.

```
library(ggplot2)
df = economics
df$month =  as.POSIXlt(df$date)$mon+1
```

I get exactly what I want when I split into monthly data manually:

```
library(zoo)
df.test = subset(df, month==1)
df.test$uempmed.ma = rollapply(df.test$unemploy,  width=3, FUN=mean, na.rm=T, 
                               fill=NA, align="right") 


  head(df.test)

         date   pce    pop psavert uempmed unemploy year month uempmed.ma
8  1968-01-31 534.7 199920     9.5     4.5     3001 1968     1         NA
20 1969-01-31 590.2 201881     6.5     4.9     2692 1969     1         NA
32 1970-01-31 635.7 204008     8.1     4.5     3453 1970     1   3048.667
44 1971-01-31 681.3 206668     9.9     6.3     4903 1971     1   3682.667
56 1972-01-31 738.4 209061     9.4     6.6     4928 1972     1   4428.000
68 1973-01-31 828.5 211120     9.5     5.2     4452 1973     1   4761.000
```

But, when I try to use the plyr package to do all months simultaneously ....

```
library(plyr)
df2 = ddply(df, .(month), mutate,
            uempmed.ma = rollapply(df$uempmed,  3, FUN=mean, na.rm=T, 
                                   fill=NA, align="right") 
)
```

....the following error is returned:

```
Error: wrong result size (478), expected 40 or 1
```

I know this should be fairly easy but, I am stumped.

Ultimately, I want the moving average series (i.e. `uempmed.ma`) to be lagged -- That is, not include the current year in the calculation. For example, the value for 1971-01-31 from above should be the average of `uempmed` for the 1968-01-31, 1969-01-31, and 1970-01-31 time periods.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`dplyr` (the new generation of `plyr`) seem to work

```
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(month) %>%
  mutate(uempmed.ma = rollapply(unemploy, width = 3, 
         FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE, fill = NA, align = "right"))
```

---

You can do it quite efficiently using base R too (certainly more efficiently than using `plyr`)

```
transform(df, uempmed.ma = ave(unemploy, month, 
                               FUN = function(x) rollapply(x, width = 3, 
                                                 FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE, 
                                                 fill = NA, align = "right")))
```

---

Or a bonus solution: using `data.table` package

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, uempmed.ma := rollapply(unemploy,  width = 3, 
                          FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE, fill = NA, 
                          align = "right"), 
          by = month]
```

Comment: thank you.  Any good ideas on how to lag the series by one year (i.e. not include the current year in the calculation)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. Is that a new question? What do you mean by *current year*? Maybe add some desired output?

Comment: don't forget to `library(zoo)`

Comment: @RobertKrzyzanowski, you probably right, though I just took it over from the OP finished. But I'll add anyways

Comment: @David Arenburg: to clarify, your solutions work great. But, I was also looking for a way to have the moving average be trailing. That is it should represent the average of the *previous* 3-years and *not* include the value for the current year/month in the moving average.

Comment: Maybe you could add `NA` in the beginning and remove last value, something like maybe: `c(NA, head(rollapply(unemploy, width = 3, FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE, fill = NA, align = "right"), -1))`